# $\frac{n!}{p^{\varepsilon_{p}(n!)}}$ congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n=a_{m}p^{m}+a_{m-1}p^{m-1}+\cdots +a_{0}$, the base $p$ representation of $n$, I have to prove that$$\frac{n!}{p^{\varepsilon_{p}(n!)}} \equiv (-1)^{\varepsilon_{p}(n!)} (a_m)! (a_{m-1})! \cdots (a_{0})! \mod{p}$$
I have done something, but not sure if i am close

Let $n=\sum_{k=0}^{m}a_{k}p^{k}$, where each $0\leq a_{i}<p$ be the radix/base $p$ representation of $n$. If $n=a_{0}$, then note that $p\nmid a_{0}$, therefore$$\frac{n!}{p^{\varepsilon_{p}(n!)}}= \frac{(a_0)!}{1}\equiv (-1)^{0}\cdot a_{0}!\mod{p}$$If $n=a_{1}p+a_{0}$, then we have$$\varepsilon_{p}(n!)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left\lfloor\frac{a_1 p+a_0}{p^k}\right\rfloor=a_1$$Now we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{n!}{p^{\varepsilon_{p}(n!)}}&=\frac{(a_1 p+a_{0})!}{p^{a_1}}
\\ &= \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{p-1} i \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} (p+i) \cdots \prod_{i=1}^{a_0}(a_{1}p+i) \cdot (p)\cdot(2p)\cdot(3p)\cdots(a_{1}p)}{p^{a_1}}
\\&\equiv \frac{(-1)^{a_1}\cdot (a_{0})!\cdot p^{a_1}\cdot (a_{1})!}{p^{a_1}}\mod{p}
\\ &\equiv (-1)^{\varepsilon_{p}(n!)}\cdot (a_{1})!\cdot (a_{0})!\mod{p}
\end{align*}We have show that the result is true if $n=a_{0}$ and $n=a_{1}p+a_{0}$.

Comment: So why not to try induction with your idea?

Comment: Thats what  I was thinking. But I am not able to proceed. Since I have prove for $n=a_{1}p+a_0$ can you assume this and prove the result for $n=a_{2}p^2+a_{1}p+a_{0}$? That would atleast give me a cue of how to go about proving. Thank you!

Comment: Notice that $n=p(a_2p+a_1)+a_0$. Does it help?

Comment: No. It doesn't. Exactly did the same. Let $n=pA_1+A_0$ where $A_1 = a_{2}p+a_1$. So the end result will be $(-1)^{e_p} . (A_1)! (A_0)! \pmod{p}$. How will i get the $(a_2)!$ term? Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have the following. Consider $n=a_mp^m+\cdots +a_1p+a_0=(a_mp^{m-1}+\cdots +a_1)p+a_0=[\cdot A_1+a_0$ then
$$\frac{n!}{p^{\nu _p(n!)}}=\prod _{i=1}^ni!=\left (\prod _{i=1}^{n-a_0}i\right )\cdot \left (\prod _{i=1}^{a_0}(p\cdot A_1+i)\right )\equiv \prod _{i=1}^ni!=\left (\prod _{i=1}^{n-a_0}i\right )\cdot a_0!\pmod p,$$
now we will have every $p-$residue $A_1$ times so we will get $(p-1)!^{A_1}$ and we will have $p$ times the factorial of $A_1$ but when all the contribution of $p$ is divided, so we will get $\frac{A_1!^p}{p^{\nu _p(A_1!)}}.$
By Wilson's theorem we will get then that
$$\frac{n!}{p^{\nu _p(n!)}}\equiv (-1)^{A_1}\cdot \frac{A_1!}{p^{\nu _p(A_1!)}}\cdot a_0!\pmod p,$$
but if you are doing induction, you probably know something about the middle term. At the end, you will have just to add the exponents of the $-1$ and use Legendre's theorem.